# Java equals or contains method?

Tags: java, equals, contains

I have a stack (Records) with the elements below:

```
first   20130512142202
second  20130512142204
third   20130512142206
fourth  20130512142209
fifth   20130512142212
```

and I want to check if a String  value (lets say "second") is referred  to somewhere else in the stack.
so i tried:

```
while(!Records.empty()) {
    String checkRecord=Records.pop().toString();
    if(checkRecord.equals("second")) {
        System.out.println(checkRecord + " found");
    }

    else {
        System.out.println(checkRecord +" not found");
    }
}

System.out.println("END OF STACK");
```

Equals returns false and that's fine, because "second" is not exactly the same with "second  (`20130512142204`)". So I need something else and  I tried `contains()` which returns true, but returns true even with:

```
string test = "second  20130512142204";
test.contains(rt);
```

Is contains()  the correct correct choice to implement what I need or should I try a different methodology/ modification of my code? 
I want to get true if and only if the string i give is part of a row of the stack.

Comment: Both methods are doing exactly what they are meant to. Can you elaborate on what do you need exactly? Post some examples and expected output..

Comment: Can't you use a map instead ? looks like your data structure is a set of pairs. Then you can easily access values/keys

Comment: Yes... both methods are doing exactly same. StartWith can be an option but i still think you should give me more better examples so that a proper answer comes to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are particularly interested in finding a String startsWith "second" from the stack example in your question. Use "".startsWith() function

So code is

```
  while(!Records.empty()){
        String checkRecord=Records.pop().toString();

        //True when the current checkRecord string startsWith "second"
        if(checkRecord.startsWith("second"))
        {

            System.out.println(checkRecord + " found");
        }else{
            System.out.println(checkRecord +" not found");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("END OF STACK");
```

---

In addition, "".contains() function must do exactly the same as above code. I do not understand why it did not work for you.